# I am making a calculator that keeps all the different sums on the screen using flutter. Not sure how to approach this

Tags: flutter, textfield, calculator

I have been trying not to have ask but I need some help. I am building my first flutter app. It's a calculator and I can get a basic one working without problems I am even getting it to evaluate with each key press, whether it be from my numbers widgets or by typing directly into the textfield.

I want to make it a bit different. I have tried to come up with the best way to do this but am not sure how. I want multiple sums to stay shown in the textfield(I presume if it needs editing I need to use  a textfield) with the result attached. (i.e  2+6+4=12 then on a new line have another 6*6=36 etc.) At any time updating the textfield with the keypad must update all the sums on screen.

I have tried to do this using just one textfield (splitting the text and adding the sums to a list then calculating each and adding them back), however seems very cumbersome and I don't think this is the best approach.  I have also made a Dynamic list of textfields , but found it difficult to index each textfield widget (dont think this is the correct approach)  Im not asking for code but ideas as to which route to take. Your help would be appreciated.